# Google Cloud appengine - editing appengine-web.xml to keep a Free Tier app in Free Tier

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-platform

My Google AppEngine appengine-web.xml file is as below. I'd like to use the max-instances setting such that my Free tier app will never leave the free tier. As I understand it, adding the following would work, followed by a re-deploy:

```
<basic-scaling>
 <max-instances>1</max-instances>
</basic-scaling>
```

Is this true? I'm actually unclear where my app.yaml  file is (i think a newer Eclipse plugin is needed to generate it).. but I am using an Eclipse Java project and my build creates the appengine-web.xml file, which is where i think these changes go, but i'm not sure.

thanks.
ben.

=======Reference: my appengine-web.xml file==========================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you understood correctly. You have to change xml file and redeploy.

According to the official documentation [appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements_basic_scaling):

Basic Scaling:

> Optional.
>
> The  element sets the number of instances for
> a module.
>
> This element can contain the following elements:
>
> **idle-timeout** Optional. The instance will be shut down this amount of
> time after receiving its last request. The default is 5 minutes.
>
> **max-instances** Required. The maximum number of instances for App
> Engine to create for this module version. This is useful to limit the
> costs of a module.

Here is an example:

```
appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>simple-app</application>
<module>default</module>
<version>uno</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<instance-class>B8</instance-class>
<basic-scaling>
  <max-instances>11</max-instances>
  <idle-timeout>10m</idle-timeout>
</basic-scaling>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the free tier, prefer the automatic-scaling. Indeed, the free tier aren't the same as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments)

In addition, take care of the size of your instance class and [read carefully this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing).

> When you are billed for instance hours, you will not see any instance classes in your billing line items. Instead, you will see the appropriate multiple of instance hours. For example, if you use an F4 instance for one hour, you do not see "F4" listed, but you see billing for four instance hours at the F1 rate.

Final details, in automatic scaling, when an instance is spawned, it's billed at least 15 minutes

> For each instance, there is an initial start up cost of 15 minutes instance time.

And 1 hour for basic and manual scaling

> Instances running in manual and basic scaling services are billed at hourly rates based on uptime. Billing begins when an instance starts and ends fifteen minutes after a manual instance shuts down or fifteen minutes after a basic instance has finished processing its last request

Comment: In fact ``<basic-scaling>`` forces the use of "B" instances, which at the moment are causing the bill to raise pretty rapidly (only few hours of "B" per day are free). While ``<automatic-scaling>`` at the moment defaults to "F1" instance, so should allow staying on Free Tier, but to be sure better also set something like ``<instance-class>F1</instance-class>``